# Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 throw "Couldn't find a metric named..."

Tags: azure, powershell

### Description

I'm trying to create new Azure Monitor Alert using PS script.
I'm using MS documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/add-azmetricalertrulev2?view=azps-5.9.0

### Steps to reproduce

$condition = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -MetricName "SqlDbDtuUsageMetric" -MetricNameSpace "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -Threshold 5

$act = New-AzActionGroup -ActionGroupId /subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/SqlDbDtuUsageAction

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "SqlDbDtuUsageAlertGt5" -ResourceGroupName {resource_group} -WindowSize 00:05:00 -Frequency 00:05:00 -TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{sql_server}/databases/vi{sql_db}" -Description "Alerting when max used DTU is > 20" -Severity 3 -ActionGroup $act -Condition $condition

### Error output

WARNING: 09:04:18 - *** The namespace for all the model classes will change from Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models in future releases.
WARNING: 09:04:18 - *** The namespace for output classes will be uniform for all classes in future releases to make it independent of modifications in the model classes.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create/update an alert rule" on target "Create/update an alert rule: SqlDbDtuUsageAlertGt5 from resource group: vi-prod-be-cin-rg".
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Couldn't find a metric named metric1. Make sure the name is correct. Activity ID: 3e7e537e-43fc-40ad-8a84-745df33e1668., Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: BadRequest
At line:1 char:1

- Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "SqlDbDtuUsageAlertGt5" -ResourceGroupN ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetricAlertRuleV2Command
  ```

### Module versions

Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

---

Script     2.2.5      Az.Accounts                         {Disable-AzDataCollection, Disable-AzContextAutosave, Enable-AzDataCollection, Enable-AzContextAutosave...}
Script     1.6.3      Az.Accounts                         {Disable-AzDataCollection, Disable-AzContextAutosave, Enable-AzDataCollection, Enable-AzContextAutosave...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.Advisor                          {Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation, Enable-AzAdvisorRecommendation, Disable-AzAdvisorRecommendation, Get-AzAdvisorConfiguration...}
Script     1.0.2      Az.Aks                              {Get-AzAks, New-AzAks, Remove-AzAks, Import-AzAksCredential...}
Script     1.1.1      Az.AnalysisServices                 {Resume-AzAnalysisServicesServer, Suspend-AzAnalysisServicesServer, Get-AzAnalysisServicesServer, Remove-AzAnalysisServicesServer...}
Script     1.3.2      Az.ApiManagement                    {Add-AzApiManagementApiToProduct, Add-AzApiManagementProductToGroup, Add-AzApiManagementRegion, Add-AzApiManagementUserToGroup...}
Script     1.0.2      Az.ApplicationInsights              {Get-AzApplicationInsights, New-AzApplicationInsights, Remove-AzApplicationInsights, Set-AzApplicationInsightsPricingPlan...}
Script     1.3.4      Az.Automation                       {Get-AzAutomationHybridWorkerGroup, Remove-AzAutomationHybridWorkerGroup, Get-AzAutomationJobOutputRecord, Import-AzAutomationDscNodeConfiguration...}
Script     1.1.2      Az.Batch                            {Remove-AzBatchAccount, Get-AzBatchAccount, Get-AzBatchAccountKey, New-AzBatchAccount...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.Billing                          {Get-AzBillingInvoice, Get-AzBillingPeriod, Get-AzEnrollmentAccount, Get-AzConsumptionBudget...}
Script     1.3.1      Az.Cdn                              {Get-AzCdnProfile, Get-AzCdnProfileSsoUrl, New-AzCdnProfile, Remove-AzCdnProfile...}
Script     1.2.1      Az.CognitiveServices                {Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccount, Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountKey, Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountSku, Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccountType...}
Script     2.7.0      Az.Compute                          {Remove-AzAvailabilitySet, Get-AzAvailabilitySet, New-AzAvailabilitySet, Update-AzAvailabilitySet...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.ContainerInstance                {New-AzContainerGroup, Get-AzContainerGroup, Remove-AzContainerGroup, Get-AzContainerInstanceLog}
Script     1.1.0      Az.ContainerRegistry                {New-AzContainerRegistry, Get-AzContainerRegistry, Update-AzContainerRegistry, Remove-AzContainerRegistry...}
Script     1.0.0      Az.CosmosDB                         {Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainer, Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainerThroughput, Get-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabase, Get-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabaseThroughput...}
Script     1.4.0      Az.DataFactory                      {Set-AzDataFactoryV2, Update-AzDataFactoryV2, Get-AzDataFactoryV2, Remove-AzDataFactoryV2...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.DataLakeAnalytics                {Get-AzDataLakeAnalyticsDataSource, New-AzDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential, Remove-AzDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential, Set-AzDataLakeAnalyticsCatalogCredential...}
Script     1.2.3      Az.DataLakeStore                    {Get-AzDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider, Remove-AzDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider, Remove-AzDataLakeStoreFirewallRule, Set-AzDataLakeStoreTrustedIdProvider...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.DeploymentManager                {Get-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource, New-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource, Set-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource, Remove-AzDeploymentManagerArtifactSource...}
Script     1.0.0      Az.DevTestLabs                      {Get-AzDtlAllowedVMSizesPolicy, Get-AzDtlAutoShutdownPolicy, Get-AzDtlAutoStartPolicy, Get-AzDtlVMsPerLabPolicy...}
Script     1.1.1      Az.Dns                              {Get-AzDnsRecordSet, New-AzDnsRecordConfig, Remove-AzDnsRecordSet, Set-AzDnsRecordSet...}
Script     1.2.2      Az.EventGrid                        {New-AzEventGridTopic, Get-AzEventGridTopic, Set-AzEventGridTopic, New-AzEventGridTopicKey...}
Script     1.4.0      Az.EventHub                         {New-AzEventHubNamespace, Get-AzEventHubNamespace, Set-AzEventHubNamespace, Remove-AzEventHubNamespace...}
Script     1.1.1      Az.FrontDoor                        {New-AzFrontDoor, Get-AzFrontDoor, Set-AzFrontDoor, Remove-AzFrontDoor...}
Script     2.0.2      Az.HDInsight                        {Get-AzHDInsightJob, New-AzHDInsightSqoopJobDefinition, Wait-AzHDInsightJob, New-AzHDInsightStreamingMapReduceJobDefinition...}
Script     1.0.0      Az.HealthcareApis                   {New-AzHealthcareApisService, Remove-AzHealthcareApisService, Set-AzHealthcareApisService, Get-AzHealthcareApisService}
Script     1.3.1      Az.IotHub                           {Add-AzIotHubKey, Get-AzIotHubEventHubConsumerGroup, Get-AzIotHubConnectionString, Get-AzIotHubJob...}
Script     1.3.1      Az.KeyVault                         {Add-AzKeyVaultCertificate, Update-AzKeyVaultCertificate, Stop-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation, Get-AzKeyVaultCertificateOperation...}
Script     1.3.1      Az.LogicApp                         {Get-AzIntegrationAccountAgreement, Get-AzIntegrationAccountAssembly, Get-AzIntegrationAccountBatchConfiguration, Get-AzIntegrationAccountCallbackUrl...}
Script     1.1.1      Az.MachineLearning                  {Move-AzMlCommitmentAssociation, Get-AzMlCommitmentAssociation, Get-AzMlCommitmentPlanUsageHistory, Remove-AzMlCommitmentPlan...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.ManagedServices                  {Get-AzManagedServicesAssignment, New-AzManagedServicesAssignment, Remove-AzManagedServicesAssignment, Get-AzManagedServicesDefinition...}
Script     1.0.1      Az.MarketplaceOrdering              {Get-AzMarketplaceTerms, Set-AzMarketplaceTerms}
Script     1.1.0      Az.Media                            {Sync-AzMediaServiceStorageKey, Set-AzMediaServiceKey, Get-AzMediaServiceKey, Get-AzMediaServiceNameAvailability...}
Script     1.4.0      Az.Monitor                          {Get-AzMetricDefinition, Get-AzMetric, Remove-AzLogProfile, Get-AzLogProfile...}
Script     1.15.0     Az.Network                          {Add-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, Get-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, New-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate, Remove-AzApplicationGatewayAuthenticationCertificate...}
Script     1.1.0      Az.NotificationHubs                 {Get-AzNotificationHub, Get-AzNotificationHubAuthorizationRule, Get-AzNotificationHubListKey, Get-AzNotificationHubPNSCredential...}
Script     1.3.3      Az.OperationalInsights              {New-AzOperationalInsightsAzureActivityLogDataSource, New-AzOperationalInsightsCustomLogDataSource, Disable-AzOperationalInsightsLinuxCustomLogCollection, Disable-AzOperationalInsightsIISLogCollection...}
Script     1.1.3      Az.PolicyInsights                   {Get-AzPolicyEvent, Get-AzPolicyState, Get-AzPolicyStateSummary, Get-AzPolicyRemediation...}
Script     1.1.0      Az.PowerBIEmbedded                  {Remove-AzPowerBIWorkspaceCollection, Get-AzPowerBIWorkspaceCollection, Get-AzPowerBIWorkspaceCollectionAccessKey, Get-AzPowerBIWorkspace...}
Script     1.4.5      Az.RecoveryServices                 {Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProperty, Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault, Get-AzRecoveryServicesVaultSettingsFile, New-AzRecoveryServicesVault...}
Script     1.1.1      Az.RedisCache                       {Remove-AzRedisCachePatchSchedule, New-AzRedisCacheScheduleEntry, Get-AzRedisCachePatchSchedule, New-AzRedisCachePatchSchedule...}
Script     1.0.2      Az.Relay                            {New-AzRelayNamespace, Get-AzRelayNamespace, Set-AzRelayNamespace, Remove-AzRelayNamespace...}
Script     1.7.0      Az.Resources                        {Get-AzProviderOperation, Remove-AzRoleAssignment, Get-AzRoleAssignment, New-AzRoleAssignment...}
Script     1.4.0      Az.ServiceBus                       {New-AzServiceBusNamespace, Get-AzServiceBusNamespace, Set-AzServiceBusNamespace, Remove-AzServiceBusNamespace...}
Script     1.2.0      Az.ServiceFabric                    {Add-AzServiceFabricApplicationCertificate, Add-AzServiceFabricClientCertificate, Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate, Add-AzServiceFabricNode...}
Script     1.1.0      Az.SignalR                          {New-AzSignalR, Get-AzSignalR, Get-AzSignalRKey, New-AzSignalRKey...}
Script     1.15.0     Az.Sql                              {Get-AzSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption, Get-AzSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryptionActivity, Set-AzSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption, Get-AzSqlDatabaseUpgradeHint...}
Script     1.8.0      Az.Storage                          {Get-AzStorageAccount, Get-AzStorageAccountKey, New-AzStorageAccount, New-AzStorageAccountKey...}
Script     1.2.1      Az.StorageSync                      {Invoke-AzStorageSyncCompatibilityCheck, New-AzStorageSyncService, Get-AzStorageSyncService, Remove-AzStorageSyncService...}
Script     1.0.0      Az.StreamAnalytics                  {Get-AzStreamAnalyticsFunction, Get-AzStreamAnalyticsDefaultFunctionDefinition, New-AzStreamAnalyticsFunction, Remove-AzStreamAnalyticsFunction...}
Script     1.0.2      Az.TrafficManager                   {Add-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderToEndpoint, Remove-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderFromEndpoint, Add-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderToProfile, Remove-AzTrafficManagerCustomHeaderFromProfile...}
Script     1.5.0      Az.Websites                         {Get-AzAppServicePlan, Set-AzAppServicePlan, New-AzAppServicePlan, Remove-AzAppServicePlan...}
Script     5.1.2      Azure                               {Get-AzureAutomationCertificate, Get-AzureAutomationConnection, New-AzureAutomationConnection, Remove-AzureAutomationConnection...}
Script     5.8.3      AzureRM.profile                     {Disable-AzureRmDataCollection, Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave, Enable-AzureRmDataCollection, Enable-AzureRmContextAutosave...}
Script     1.0.1      Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.V... {Get-OperationValidation, Invoke-OperationValidation}
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider, Get-PackageSource...}
Script     3.4.0      Pester                              {Describe, Context, It, Should...}
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Install-Module, Find-Module, Save-Module, Update-Module...}
Script     2.0.0      PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption...}

```
  Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

---

Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppBackgroundTask                   {Disable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Enable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Set-AppBackgroundTaskResourcePolicy, Unregister-AppBackgroundTask...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    AppLocker                           {Get-AppLockerFileInformation, Get-AppLockerPolicy, New-AppLockerPolicy, Set-AppLockerPolicy...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppvClient                          {Add-AppvClientConnectionGroup, Add-AppvClientPackage, Add-AppvPublishingServer, Disable-Appv...}
Manifest   2.0.1.0    Appx                                {Add-AppxPackage, Get-AppxPackage, Get-AppxPackageManifest, Remove-AppxPackage...}
Script     1.0.0.0    AssignedAccess                      {Clear-AssignedAccess, Get-AssignedAccess, Set-AssignedAccess}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    BitLocker                           {Unlock-BitLocker, Suspend-BitLocker, Resume-BitLocker, Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    BitsTransfer                        {Add-BitsFile, Complete-BitsTransfer, Get-BitsTransfer, Remove-BitsTransfer...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    BranchCache                         {Add-BCDataCacheExtension, Clear-BCCache, Disable-BC, Disable-BCDowngrading...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    CimCmdlets                          {Get-CimAssociatedInstance, Get-CimClass, Get-CimInstance, Get-CimSession...}
Manifest   1.0        ConfigCI                            {Get-SystemDriver, New-CIPolicyRule, New-CIPolicy, Get-CIPolicy...}
Manifest   1.0        ConfigDefender                      {Get-MpPreference, Set-MpPreference, Add-MpPreference, Remove-MpPreference...}
Manifest   1.0        Defender                            {Get-MpPreference, Set-MpPreference, Add-MpPreference, Remove-MpPreference...}
Manifest   1.0.2.0    DeliveryOptimization                {Delete-DeliveryOptimizationCache, Set-DeliveryOptimizationStatus, Get-DeliveryOptimizationLog, Get-DeliveryOptimizationLogAnalysis...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    DirectAccessClientComponents        {Disable-DAManualEntryPointSelection, Enable-DAManualEntryPointSelection, Get-DAClientExperienceConfiguration, Get-DAEntryPointTableItem...}
Script     3.0        Dism                                {Add-AppxProvisionedPackage, Add-WindowsDriver, Add-WindowsCapability, Add-WindowsImage...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    DnsClient                           {Resolve-DnsName, Clear-DnsClientCache, Get-DnsClient, Get-DnsClientCache...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    EventTracingManagement              {Start-EtwTraceSession, New-EtwTraceSession, Get-EtwTraceSession, Update-EtwTraceSession...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    HgsClient                           {Get-HgsAttestationBaselinePolicy, Get-HgsClientConfiguration, Test-HgsClientConfiguration, Set-HgsClientConfiguration...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    HgsDiagnostics                      {New-HgsTraceTarget, Get-HgsTrace, Get-HgsTraceFileData, Test-HgsTraceTarget}
Binary     1.0.0.0    HostComputeService                  {Get-ComputeProcess, Stop-ComputeProcess}
Manifest   1.0.0.1    HostNetworkingService               {Remove-HnsNamespace, Remove-HnsEndpoint, Get-HnsEndpoint, Remove-HnsPolicyList...}
Binary     2.0.0.0    Hyper-V                             {Add-VMAssignableDevice, Add-VMDvdDrive, Add-VMFibreChannelHba, Add-VMGpuPartitionAdapter...}
Binary     1.1        Hyper-V                             {Add-VMDvdDrive, Add-VMFibreChannelHba, Add-VMHardDiskDrive, Add-VMMigrationNetwork...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    International                       {Get-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride, Set-WinDefaultInputMethodOverride, Get-WinHomeLocation, Set-WinHomeLocation...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    iSCSI                               {Get-IscsiTargetPortal, New-IscsiTargetPortal, Remove-IscsiTargetPortal, Update-IscsiTargetPortal...}
Script     1.0.0.0    ISE                                 {New-IseSnippet, Import-IseSnippet, Get-IseSnippet}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Kds                                 {Add-KdsRootKey, Get-KdsRootKey, Test-KdsRootKey, Set-KdsConfiguration...}
Manifest   1.0.1.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive        {Compress-Archive, Expand-Archive}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics    {Get-WinEvent, Get-Counter, Import-Counter, Export-Counter...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Host           {Start-Transcript, Stop-Transcript}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts  {Add-LocalGroupMember, Disable-LocalUser, Enable-LocalUser, Get-LocalGroup...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-ItemProperty, Join-Path...}
Script     1.0        Microsoft.PowerShell.ODataUtils     Export-ODataEndpointProxy
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Security       {Get-Acl, Set-Acl, Get-PfxCertificate, Get-Credential...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Format-List, Format-Custom, Format-Table, Format-Wide...}
Manifest   3.0.0.0    Microsoft.WSMan.Management          {Disable-WSManCredSSP, Enable-WSManCredSSP, Get-WSManCredSSP, Set-WSManQuickConfig...}
Manifest   1.0        MMAgent                             {Disable-MMAgent, Enable-MMAgent, Set-MMAgent, Get-MMAgent...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    MsDtc                               {New-DtcDiagnosticTransaction, Complete-DtcDiagnosticTransaction, Join-DtcDiagnosticResourceManager, Receive-DtcDiagnosticTransaction...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetAdapter                          {Disable-NetAdapter, Disable-NetAdapterBinding, Disable-NetAdapterChecksumOffload, Disable-NetAdapterEncapsulatedPacketTaskOffload...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetConnection                       {Get-NetConnectionProfile, Set-NetConnectionProfile}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetDiagnostics                      Get-NetView
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetEventPacketCapture               {New-NetEventSession, Remove-NetEventSession, Get-NetEventSession, Set-NetEventSession...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetLbfo                             {Add-NetLbfoTeamMember, Add-NetLbfoTeamNic, Get-NetLbfoTeam, Get-NetLbfoTeamMember...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetNat                              {Get-NetNat, Get-NetNatExternalAddress, Get-NetNatStaticMapping, Get-NetNatSession...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetQos                              {Get-NetQosPolicy, Set-NetQosPolicy, Remove-NetQosPolicy, New-NetQosPolicy}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    NetSecurity                         {Get-DAPolicyChange, New-NetIPsecAuthProposal, New-NetIPsecMainModeCryptoProposal, New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoProposal...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetSwitchTeam                       {New-NetSwitchTeam, Remove-NetSwitchTeam, Get-NetSwitchTeam, Rename-NetSwitchTeam...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetTCPIP                            {Get-NetIPAddress, Get-NetIPInterface, Get-NetIPv4Protocol, Get-NetIPv6Protocol...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetworkConnectivityStatus           {Get-DAConnectionStatus, Get-NCSIPolicyConfiguration, Reset-NCSIPolicyConfiguration, Set-NCSIPolicyConfiguration}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetworkSwitchManager                {Disable-NetworkSwitchEthernetPort, Enable-NetworkSwitchEthernetPort, Get-NetworkSwitchEthernetPort, Remove-NetworkSwitchEthernetPortIPAddress...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    NetworkTransition                   {Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding, Disable-NetDnsTransitionConfiguration, Disable-NetIPHttpsProfile, Disable-NetNatTransitionConfiguration...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PcsvDevice                          {Get-PcsvDevice, Start-PcsvDevice, Stop-PcsvDevice, Restart-PcsvDevice...}
Binary     1.0.0.0    PersistentMemory                    {Get-PmemDisk, Get-PmemPhysicalDevice, Get-PmemUnusedRegion, New-PmemDisk...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PKI                                 {Add-CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer, Export-Certificate, Export-PfxCertificate, Get-CertificateAutoEnrollmentPolicy...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PnpDevice                           {Get-PnpDevice, Get-PnpDeviceProperty, Enable-PnpDevice, Disable-PnpDevice}
Manifest   1.1        PrintManagement                     {Add-Printer, Add-PrinterDriver, Add-PrinterPort, Get-PrintConfiguration...}
Binary     1.0.12     ProcessMitigations                  {Get-ProcessMitigation, Set-ProcessMitigation, ConvertTo-ProcessMitigationPolicy}
Script     3.0        Provisioning                        {Install-ProvisioningPackage, Export-ProvisioningPackage, Install-TrustedProvisioningCertificate, Export-Trace...}
Manifest   1.1        PSDesiredStateConfiguration         {Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager, Start-DscConfiguration, Test-DscConfiguration, Publish-DscConfiguration...}
Script     1.0.0.0    PSDiagnostics                       {Disable-PSTrace, Disable-PSWSManCombinedTrace, Disable-WSManTrace, Enable-PSTrace...}
Binary     1.1.0.0    PSScheduledJob                      {New-JobTrigger, Add-JobTrigger, Remove-JobTrigger, Get-JobTrigger...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    PSWorkflow                          {New-PSWorkflowExecutionOption, New-PSWorkflowSession, nwsn}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    PSWorkflowUtility                   Invoke-AsWorkflow
Manifest   1.0.0.0    ScheduledTasks                      {Get-ScheduledTask, Set-ScheduledTask, Register-ScheduledTask, Unregister-ScheduledTask...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SecureBoot                          {Confirm-SecureBootUEFI, Set-SecureBootUEFI, Get-SecureBootUEFI, Format-SecureBootUEFI...}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    ServiceFabric                       {Get-ServiceFabricServiceName, Get-ServiceFabricApplicationName, Approve-ServiceFabricRepairTask, Remove-ServiceFabricTestState...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SmbShare                            {Get-SmbShare, Remove-SmbShare, Set-SmbShare, Block-SmbShareAccess...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    SmbWitness                          {Get-SmbWitnessClient, Move-SmbWitnessClient, gsmbw, msmbw...}
Manifest   1.0.0.1    StartLayout                         {Export-StartLayout, Import-StartLayout, Export-StartLayoutEdgeAssets, Get-StartApps}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Storage                             {Add-InitiatorIdToMaskingSet, Add-PartitionAccessPath, Add-PhysicalDisk, Add-StorageFaultDomain...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    StorageBusCache                     {Clear-StorageBusDisk, Disable-StorageBusCache, Disable-StorageBusDisk, Enable-StorageBusCache...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    TLS                                 {New-TlsSessionTicketKey, Enable-TlsSessionTicketKey, Disable-TlsSessionTicketKey, Export-TlsSessionTicketKey...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    TroubleshootingPack                 {Get-TroubleshootingPack, Invoke-TroubleshootingPack}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    TrustedPlatformModule               {Get-Tpm, Initialize-Tpm, Clear-Tpm, Unblock-Tpm...}
Binary     2.1.639.0  UEV                                 {Clear-UevConfiguration, Clear-UevAppxPackage, Restore-UevBackup, Set-UevTemplateProfile...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    VpnClient                           {Add-VpnConnection, Set-VpnConnection, Remove-VpnConnection, Get-VpnConnection...}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    Wdac                                {Get-OdbcDriver, Set-OdbcDriver, Get-OdbcDsn, Add-OdbcDsn...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    Whea                                {Get-WheaMemoryPolicy, Set-WheaMemoryPolicy}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    WindowsDeveloperLicense             {Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense, Unregister-WindowsDeveloperLicense, Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration}
Script     1.0        WindowsErrorReporting               {Enable-WindowsErrorReporting, Disable-WindowsErrorReporting, Get-WindowsErrorReporting}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    WindowsSearch                       {Get-WindowsSearchSetting, Set-WindowsSearchSetting}
Manifest   1.0.0.0    WindowsUpdate                       Get-WindowsUpdateLog
Manifest   1.0.0.2    WindowsUpdateProvider               {Get-WUAVersion, Get-WULastInstallationDate, Get-WULastScanSuccessDate, Get-WUIsPendingReboot...}

```
  Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Azure Information Protection\Powershell
```

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

---

Binary     2.6.111.0  AzureInformationProtection          {Clear-AIPAuthentication, Get-AIPFileStatus, New-AIPCustomPermissions, Export-AIPLogs...}

Comment: Please make sure that the metric `SqlDbDtuUsageMetric` actually exists in the specified Metric namespace. The cmdlet is unable to find this metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error, the MetricNameSpace `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases` does not contain metric `SqlDbDtuUsageMetric`. Regarding the supported metric,  please use the following command to get

```
Connect-AzAccount

Get-AzMetricDefinition -MetricNamespace "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases" -ResourceId "<the resource id of your spl database>"
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftsqlserversdatabases) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetricdefinition?view=azps-5.9.0)